# Is it true that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n/n^2<\infty$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $a_n\geq0$ real numbers and $\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\leq C$ for a constant $C$, for all $n$. Is it true that $\sum_n \dfrac{a_n}{n^2}<\infty$?

So basically I am asking if boundedness of Cesaro means implies series convergence.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Let $S_0=0,$ $S_n= \sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k, n\ge 1.$ Then

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{a_k}{k^2}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(S_k-S_{k-1})}{k^2}.$$

Sum by parts.

Comment: Thank you very much!